# Finding Open Source Data

Tags: open-source

I was wondering if anyone had any tips for finding the data I need... for one of my projects I need to find data showing grocery stores, shopping and other essential businesses in California (specifically the central coast).

Is there a way to get this data from somewhere like Google Maps?

Comment: google maps isn't open source or open data

Answer (score 2):

See the link below. However, the last time I used it (about 2 years ago), there was a small fee associated with it.

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places

The simplest way to get the data is to use the specialized library like https://pypi.org/project/googlemaps/1.0.2/

Comment: anything with a cost associated is inherently not open data. thank you for contributing, and your second link makes this answer valid. the first is not optimal though.

Comment: Oh, I see. The fee was if you get more that 3000 entries per day or so.

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMaps has this data. You can try/test it out using [OverPass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/#).
This tool isn't going to do the entire state of California, but if you choose the manually select bbox option and pick a locality, it will show you what is available for that locality.
I zoomed into San Francisco and manually drew the bbox around it, then clicked run and it populated the map.
If you click on the data option in the top right of the UI, you'll see the JSON that is powering/populating the map.